# Inverse of incomplete elliptic function of first kind

Tags: calculus, special-functions

How to find the inverse of elliptic function of first kind in term of angle of integration $\varphi$? This [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) say that Jacobi amplitude $\varphi = \text{am}(u)$ gives the value  of angle $\varphi$. How do I expand the Jacobi amplitude in series so that I can numerically calculate the angle $\varphi$ as function of $u$.

Answer (score 2):

There's Fourier expansion:

$$\operatorname{am} (u,k)=
\frac{\pi u}{2K}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \frac{n\pi u}{K}}{n\cosh \frac{n\pi K'}{K}} $$

where $K\equiv K(k)=F \left( \frac{\pi}{2},k \right)$ and $K'\equiv K(\sqrt{1-k^2})$.

By the ways, its better to use symbolic software to ease your work.

For example, in *Mathematica*

```
JacobiAmplitude[u,m]
```

for $\operatorname{am} (u,\sqrt{m})$

Comment: this seems related to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Expansion_in_terms_of_the_nome)

Comment: As you have shown, the inverse of $\text F(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ is $\text{am}(x,y)$, but what if I wanted to solve for the other argument, $y$?

Comment: Applying [InverseSeries](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseSeries.html). for [22.10(ii)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.10#ii), [22.16.7](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16#E7), [22.16.8](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16#E8), etc.