# Product of elliptic integrals given by inverse ellipses

Tags: hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

I'm doing some computations in a specific case of a problem about ellipses, and I was wondering if there was a nice solution for the following product:

$$E( 1-b^2/a^2)E( 1-a^2/b^2)$$

Where $E(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind with parameter $m=k^2$.

Geometric considerations suggest that this should be $\pi^2/4$, and while that looks spiritually related to the product of the infinite series representations of $E$, I haven't the faintest on how to get to this evaluation, or even if it is correct.

This is equivalent to showing that:

$$_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};1;\left(1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)\right){}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};1;\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)\right) = 1$$

So this question can be rephrased in terms of known formulae for products of Gauss's hypergeometric function.

Please let me know if the notation is wrong/confusing-- the ways that elliptic integrals are written is still a little fuzzy to me.

Comment: Note that $$aE\left( 1-\frac{b^2}{a^2} \right)=bE\left( 1-\frac{a^2}{b^2} \right)$$ your conjecture is unlikely to be true.

Comment: What do you mean by  `a nice solution for the following product` ?

Comment: @NgChungTak how do you get that identity? I have that: $$aE(1-b^2/a^2) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{a^2 - (a^2-b^2)\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$ and $$bE(1-a^2/b^2) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{b^2 - (b^2 - a^2)\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$ which are not the same, by my analysis.

Comment: @William, by $$\int_0^\alpha f(x) \, dx=\int_0^\alpha f(\alpha-x) \, dx$$ then the roles of $a$ and $b$ can be flipped.

Comment: @William, see more about the clockwise and anti-clockwise conventions of my older post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284133/xt-a-cost-yt-b-sint-in-terms-of-the-arc-length-s/4284944#4284944).

Comment: Thanks-- I will now reproduce your implied derivation, if you don't mind verifying that it is correct. In the formulation in my comment, replace $\sin^2\theta$ with $1-\sin^2(\theta)$, since in this case we may replace $\sin^2\theta$ with $\sin^2(\pi/2 - \theta)$ without changing the integral, and $\sin^2(\pi/2 -\theta) = 1-\sin^2\theta$. However, after simplification, this transforms $aE(1-b^2/a^2)$ into $bE(1-a^2/b^2)$, and vice versa.

Comment: And I’m unsure about the reason you mentioned the choices of convention? Do you mind elaborating on why you included that info? If you want to write an answer, I would happily accept it.