# Parameterize the ellipse $x^2+y^2=1, 2=y+z$ with respect to arc length

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Just parameterizing by a general parameter $t$ I got $\mathbf{r}(t) = \langle \cos t, \sin t, 2-\sin t\rangle$, which in the arc length formula would be: $$\mathbf{s}(t) = \int_0^t \sqrt{(-\sin u)^2 + \cos^2u + (-\cos u)^2}\ du = \int_0^t \sqrt{1+\cos^2u}\, du= \, ?$$
Am I doing something wrong, or is there just no way to parameterize by arc length?

Comment: You forgot the square root (and the $du$) in the second expression of the integral.

Comment: There's no closed form to parametrized an ellipse by its arclength.  See [*another post*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284133/xt-a-cost-yt-b-sint-in-terms-of-the-arc-length-s) for your interest.