# Normalize speed of parametric function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, conic-sections, parametric

I have a parametric function for an ellipse:

$$f\left(t\right)=\left(a\cos\left(t\right),b\sin\left(t\right)\right)$$

As the function goes linearly through t from 0 to 2pi, the point speeds up near the minor axis and slows down near the major axis. I don't want this, I want it to have a constant speed.

I have tried taking the derivative, but then I don't know what to do with the derivative to make the parametric function output a constant speed. I have tried plugging the linearly increasing value into functions that I put inside the parametric function, trying to find a function that increases at a rate inverse to the speed. I have been using Desmos for my work.

In other words, how can I derive a function that creates the same shape over time but has a constant speed or derivative of magnitude of velocity? As well as this, can the same method be applied to any parametric function?

Comment: I think you'd have to use elliptic integrals, which are non-elementary functions.

Comment: The arclength $s$ is given by $$\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2=\lVert f'(t)\rVert^2=a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t$$ $$s=\int\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t}\,dt,$$ and then you'd have to invert this function, solving for $t$ in terms of $s$.

Comment: Unit speed parametrization is equivalent to parametrization by arclength.  Please refer to my post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284133/xt-a-cost-yt-b-sint-in-terms-of-the-arc-length-s/4284944#4284944).